# How are terms in SS (corrected sum of squares) independent?

Tags: experiment-design, independence, degrees-of-freedom, sums-of-squares

[image: From Douglas C. Montgomery's Design and Analysis of Experiments, Pg. 32]

What does the highlighted test mean? How are the terms not independent? Can someone elaborate in detail?

Comment: As the text points out, they sum to zero, and therefore cannot be either functionally or statistically independent.